# How to Bubbling press event from inner Touchable to outer Touchable in React-Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I've 2 nested `Touchable`s, I would like to capture the `onPress` event in either the outer `Touchable` and the inner `Touchable`, but only the inner one will fire the `onPress` event, so we can say that the event is not propagated to the parent element

I'm using React-Native 0.57

This is my snack [example](https://snack.expo.io/@david92/bubbling-event).

I also repost my render code here:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => alert('outer')}
    style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', width: 200, height: 200 }}>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => alert('inner')}
        style={{ backgroundColor: 'green', width: 100, height: 100 }}
    />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

How you can see only the inner alert or the outer alert are showed. 
Instead I would like to show either the outer and the inner alert pressing on the green View...

The code is a simplified version, in the real case the inner `Touchable` is a component that can be used in various scenario, either inside a `Touchable`, either in non Touchable component

Comment: why do have two ```TouchableOpacity``` component nested. just remove the one which you don't want replace with ```View```.

Comment: The code is a simplified version, in the real case the inner `Touchable` is a component that can be used in various scenario, either inside a `Touchable`, either in non Touchable component

Comment: replace out ```TouchableOpacity``` with ```VIew```

Comment: Sorry but this is not the answer to my question, with your solution the behavior of the app will be very different. I want one event firings pressing on red block(not on green), 2 events firing pressing on green block

Comment: @David i can see both answers are not great solutions, did you find a solution?

Comment: Have you found the solution to this? I am having a similar problem but just on iOS, on Android the nesting is working well. Any idea?

Comment: @halbano Nope, not using the Touchable of react-native. So in your case the event is propagated to the parent? The only way that I found to propagate the event is replacing the Touchable of react-native with the Touchable of react-native-gesture-handler

Comment: @ZiaUlRehmanMughal sorry, I had not seen your comment...anyway, my last comment is also in response to you

Answer (score -2):

If you want to call the other `TouchableOpacity`'s `onPress` handler when one is triggered, just call it from the `onPress` handler of the one that is triggered.

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={myHandler}
    style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', width: 200, height: 200 }}>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={myOtherHandler}
        style={{ backgroundColor: 'green', width: 100, height: 100 }}
    />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

If `myOtherHandler` is called by the inner-most `TouchableOpacity`'s `onPress`, you call `myHandler` like this:

```
cost myOtherHandler = () => {
   myHandler(); 
   // ...other stuff
}
```

Comment: yes, it could be a solution, but my code is a semplified version, in the original version the inner `Touchable` is a reusable component, so it don't know if there is an external `Touchable`. Moreover it is not only a problem for the `onPress`, but also `onLongPress` and other press event.

Answer (score -2):

You could make the reusable component render conditionally either with `View` or `TouchableOpacity` depending on a property you pass it.

If you always want the outer component to trigger this will probably do the trick

Comment: But if a rendere the inner component without the `Touchable`, I loose the inner `onPress` event

Comment: If your custom component has a property such as 
`<CustomComponent renderWithTouchable={true} />` then you can control if you're rendering with a view or with a touchable. In the case where the component has a `TouchableOpacity` around it that you want to take precedence you just set renderWithTouchable={true}